# How do I make a reusable component for dialog or the modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to make a reusable component for dialog that has a yes or no button at the bottom, where 'yes' would be a button type of submit. Since I would like to create a dialog to ask the user whether they are sure with their entered information before submitting it.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button type="submit" color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the logic to make a reusable component. Example:

DialogButtons.jsx:

```
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
export const DialogButtons = ({handleClose}) => {
   return(
      <DialogActions>
          <Button type="submit" color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
    )
}
```

Then you gotta import this component (assuming you will have different handleClose for each different usage, if not then don't use  handleClose as props, but define it in this component):

AnyComponent:

```
import {DialogButtons} from './path/to/DialogButtons'

const handleClose = () => /* define your handleClose function */
...
return(
  ...
   <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
        {"Use Google's location service?"}
   </DialogTitle>
   <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
      </DialogContentText>
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogButtons handleClose={handleClose} />
  ...
)
```